# Does not contain architecture information for i386

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

When I compile my project I get this error:

> warning: (i386) /Users/Desktop/aug_9/iOSSample/SD_2.0.a(sdk743.o) object file '/Users/Desktop/aug_9/iOSSample/SD_2.0.a(sdk743.o)' doesn't contain architecture information for i386.

Do I need to add i386 in "Valid Architectures" in the build settings?

Can anyone advise me on how to fix this warning?

Comment: in build setting => build options => "debug information formate" i made it for stabs  then i did not get any warrning! for i386 I do not know how its happened? can any one tell me why its like that

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that you are trying to run in the simulator, and a library you are using does not support the simulator.

You might want to either check if the library has a build for the simulator, or just test your app on a real device.